# Excel Workbook Versioning via SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, vba

I have an Excel workbook with several SharePoint data connections that builds up a dashboard of various statistics. My issue is that there have been several different versions of the dashboard, and I need to make sure that everyone keeps up to date. To this date I have done the following :

The front worksheet of the dashboard has the version number of that sheet in cell Z1.

On SharePoint I have created a list containing the latest version number of the dashboard.

On the dashboard I have created a data connection to the SharePoint list containing the version latest number, which populates a hidden sheet on the dashboard.

On opening the workbook, a modal form pops up. In the load of that form, it performs a check between the local version number (cell z1) and the latest version number on the hidden sheet.

The problem that I am having is that the version check in the modal form is being executed before the workbook data refreshes - not good.

Is there any way that I can get the version check to occur after the data connections have all refreshed, or is there a simple way that I can get the latest version number from SharePoint directly in the vb code of the modal form.

Cheers, Pete

Comment: assuming the Modal Form opens from the `Workbook_Open` event, you could perhaps put a timer to have the form open after say 10 secs or whatever time you wish to wait for the data connections to refresh. You could also set each data connection to not refresh on opening and refresh it through code ... so code would be refresh connections ... then open form

Comment: The whole refresh takes over a minute (there's quite a lot of connections and data), so a timer probably wouldn't work. But if I could force the refresh of the list containing the latest version first, that would be pretty quick. Do you know the VB to refresh the data connection by any chance ?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` is a general way to refresh all connections. You can refresh an individual connection via `ThisWorkbook.Connections("myConnection").Refresh` Google search for more help. You may need to place some `Timer` or `Sleep` commands or `DoEvents` to allow the connection time to refresh before moving onto the next line of code.

Comment: Have you considered putting the Excel workbook itself in a document library on SharePoint? It seems like SharePoint's document-level versioning would circumvent the need for homebrewed version-checking code.

Comment: Scott - thanks for that man, looks perfect, I'll work on it now.

Comment: Thriggle - in an ideal world, SP versioning through a library would work great, sadly my audience would be likely to ignore the notifications :(

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my solution. I disabled the refresh on open to the versioning list and added VB into the form initialise in the modal form to perform that refresh. Because the refresh command is before the version check code, I know that the version check is looking at the latest data and not a pre-refresh button. Thanks Scott.